# Replace "/" in a string using shell script

Tags: linux

```
PATH="/dir1/subdir1"
```

Want to replace "/" with "-" from the above string
and the result should be

-dir1-subdir1

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) for that since you want to replace a single character with another one:

```sh
echo $PATH | tr "/" "-"
```

Result is: `-dir1-subdir1`

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can use a pattern substitution of the form `${parameter//pattern/string}` to replace all matches of `pattern` with `string`:

```
echo "${PATH//\//-}"
```

Note that your pattern string `/` must be escaped with `\/`.

Comment: Thanks, Freddy! I tried this but got the error "Bad substitution"

Comment: Hmm, it seems it also works without escaping (`echo "${PATH////-}"`), but I can't reproduce the error. Tested on bash 4.4.12 and 5.0.3.

Comment: No, it doesn't work for me. It gives me the same error

Comment: What's your  bash version? I do get a `Bad substitution` error in `dash`, but it also works in my `ksh` and `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the more detailed version.

```
$ var="001244abc"
$ replace="polo"
$ echo ${var//001244/$replace}
poloabc
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: I want to replace the '/' from my string. It could not work with the ${var////$replace} or ${var//\//$replace}